# In Google Chrome, are there better/additional ways to debug jQuery other than the element inspector?

Tags: jquery, debugging

Is there a jQuery debugger specifically for Chrome? Can't seem to find one.

EDIT: What I really mean is this: Is there a debugger made specifically for debugging jQuery, not just javascript in general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use Chrome's built-in debugging tools. Press CTRL + Shift + I to have the debugging tools appear. Use the "Scripts" section to debug scripts and the "Console" section to test stuff and as you mentioned, you can also inspect the elements that jQuery manipulate.

If you can't get the debugger to stop in your code, explicitly add a debug statement via the keyword debugger. Remember to remove this before deploying to prod. A good way to ensure you remove it, is to compress your scripts using YuiCompress, . Not only will it compress the script, but it will also fail to compress if there are debugger statements in the client-side code.

Comment: So for example just put `debugger;`?

Comment: @trusktr - There's also FireBug Lite for Chrome, http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome, but it's not as good as the built-in tools.

Comment: Cool, I see that the browser will pause execution at that point. So i guess that's a good way to see if a certain part of code is being reached (executed) when expected?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [firbug](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/)?

Comment: I've tried that before... that seems to be less featurefull than Chrome Inspector though... How would this benefit debugging jQuery over using Chrome Inspector?

Comment: You can use the console, it is a fully featured FB console with object property mapping and all. What functionality do you miss using FB?

Comment: Hmmmmm... I'll try that... I never really used FB so i wasn't all too familiar with it because I've always preferred chrome as a browser... I'll check it out again but i'll be sure to dive into the features of FBLite this time and see how it goes.